# Hide TabBar Item #2 after collectionView reload Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have 2 collection views in 2 separate viewcontrollers which is inside a tabbar. I'm trying to hide tabbar item 2, until tabbar 1 is loaded. Do we have any way to hide a certain tab bar item?? Initially in viewWillAppear I want to hide tabBar Item.. Here is the code that I have :

Hide Tab Bar 2

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //HIDE TABBAR2
}
```

Show Tab Bar 2

```
- (void)loadCollectionView
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{}
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      //Unhide TabBar
                                  }];

}
```

Comment: You can simply start with a single item in the tab bar items array, and add the second itm to the arrach and call 'setItems' with the updated array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove that view controller from your `tabbar`, you cant hide specific tabbar item! So you can manage it like,

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllersArr = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

[viewControllersArr removeObjectAtIndex:1];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllersArr animated:YES];
```

and when you get your collection view data or when you want to show second tab then you can do like

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllersArr = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

UIViewController *yourSeconVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryboardIdentifier"]; // or whatever way your view controller is for second tab

[viewControllersArr addObject:yourSeconVc];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllersArr animated:YES];
```

Comment: Your answer was great! It almost made the job by itself. I just had minimal problems regarding multiple reloading of data, but i solved it. Thank you so much!

Comment: One quick question, how do you call a certain view controller without reinitializing it?

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking! Are you asking about switching tabs ?

Comment: Nope nope. Its kinda different question, I just want to know how would you call a view controller that is already initialized?

Comment: You can keep your view controller in instance variable! and can add or remove that view controller to array of viewcontrollers

Answer (score 1):

Subclass a `UITabBarController` (call it e.g. `MainTabController`). In interface builder set the class type of your tab bar controller object to be of type `MainTabController`.

In `MainTabController` create a strong property to store the second view controller (the one that will be hidden):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *secondTabVC;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Store the second tab's VC for later
self.secondTabVC = self.viewControllers[1];

// Hide the second tab's VC
self.viewControllers = @[self.viewControllers[0]];
```

Once your data has loaded:

```
// Show the second tab's VC
self.viewControllers = @[self.viewControllers[0], self.secondTabVC];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [_tabController setViewControllers:@[viewcontroller1,viewcontroller3]];

}
```

Show Tab 2 here

```
- (void)loadCollectionView
{
 [self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{}

completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
    [_tabController setViewControllers:@[viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2,viewcontroller3]];
                              }];
  }
```